# Koala-Framework Website doesn't show first page

Tags: php, content-management-system, koala-framework

I got a question about a special php framework called Koala-Framework.

I've set up an apache2 on my virtual ubuntu OS, added a virtual host reserved only for my first website with this cms, also added the hosts entry and followed the tutorial on http://www.koala-framework.org/about/cms/installation , but if I enter the local domain (in my case the configured `kwf-cms-demo.localhost`), I'm only redirected to see the folder-structure and not the downloaded demo-website...

Which DocumentRoot the virtual hosts needs to be redirecting? (Because I think this could be the root of this problem...)

**PS:** 
`/var/www/kwf-cms-demo$ php bootstrap.php setup` returns:

> Application seems to be set up already. (update file exists)

so, I think the setup has to be finished without any problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Apache isn't starting up the bootstrap.php because the rewrite rules in .htaccess are not honored.

Enable mod_rewrite like that:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also see point 5 here:
http://www.koala-framework.org/about/server_requirements/ubuntu_example_configuration